# Div Resize according To image Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had two div in First Div had one image if i click of image left Div have to Re-size Right side Div have to show full page content and then if i click image again right side div have  go to original position ..how to achieve this??

```
 <div style="border: 2px solid red;float:left;width:10%;height:400px "> <a href>Image Click</a></div>
<div style="border: 2px solid Blue;float:left;width:50%;height:500px "> Content to show in full page</div>
```

Comment: Any chance you could re-write the question into something readable? A bit of grammar and punctuation wouldn't go amiss? Basically it's difficult to understand what you mean...

Comment: [this might help](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7N8/ Demo link

Answer (score 0):

As you have not given any id/class to the image div you can try this:

```
$('div').find('a').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var height = $(this).closest('div').css('height');
   if (height === "400px") {
      $(this).closest('div').css('height', 'auto');
   } else {
      $(this).closest('div').css('height', '400px');
   }
});
```

#### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X927K/1/)

Comment: @user3331535 checkout the updated answer with a demo.

Comment: u r reduce height but i want is .if user click an left side  div image have to shrink to particular width . the right side div have to show in full page not reducing a height

Comment: _shrink to particular width_ you mean its height?

Comment: Sir i mean is expandable and collapsible Div

Comment: @user3331535 you can have a look at the updated answer and the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two classes then add or remove the class from the`<div class="smaller">` tag depending on the click. 
the classes can be something like this:

```
.bigger
{
border: 2px solid Blue;
float:left;
width:50%;
height:500px
}
.smaller{
border: 2px solid red;
float:left;
width:10%;
height:400px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

**HTML**

```
 <div id="fdiv" style="border: 2px solid red;float:left;width:7%;height:400px "> <a href>Image Click</a></div>
<div id="sdiv" style="border: 2px solid Blue;float:left;width:50%;height:500px "> Content to show in full page</div>
```

**JS**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var swidth=$('#sdiv').width();
$('#fdiv a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

     var dupwidth=swidth;
            $('#sdiv').animate({ 'height': ($('#sdiv').height() == 500) ? 700 : 500 ,'width': ($('#sdiv').width() == swidth) ? parseInt(dupwidth)*1.75 : swidth }, 200);

        });

        });

    </script>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kiranramchandran/eMq9L/1/)**